# Driver for TP-LINK TL-WN721N Wi-Fi Adapter

Tags: macos, network, wifi, imac, driver

I used to plug in my TP-LINK TL-WN721N Wi-Fi adapter in a port in my old computer that used to run Windows. That's how I connected to the internet, but now I bought an iMac which I couldn't connect to the internet.

Is there a kext to use or a hack to try to get it working on my iMac? I also learned that similar chipsets used in Wi-Fi adapters can lead to similar experience using different adapters, so I searched [WikiDevi](http://wikidevi.com) to find similar products with supported OS X drivers. I am running OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Note: AirPort is malfunctioning, that's why I need the adapter to connect ..

Comment: If you are looking for help in getting your AirPort working, please consider asking a new question for this.

Comment: I managed to make a similar model from TP-LINK work by booting in Linux, taking note of the wi-fi chipset model with `lsusb` (it was a Ralink) and downloading the OS X driver from the Ralink website. Unfortunately I don't have the adapter nor the Mac here with me, so I can't give you a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the TP-Link company website, TL-WN721N is only supported under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The TP-Link website does state that the TL-WN721N wifi adapter is only supported by windows. However, you may be able to install drivers for the *chipset* of your adapter, possibly allowing it to work. Once you have determined the chipset of your adapter, you may be able to download unix drivers for it from the chipset manufacturers' website, or, from another company who is licensed to use the chipset. *(sidenote as an example- I use a USB-HDMI adapter, and while there were no OSX drivers provided by the company who sold the product, I was able to acquire drivers through the chipset manufacturer's website)* Alternatively, you may reinstall OSX to regain functionality of Airport Utility.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the built-in Airport in the Mac? Set up Network Preferences or just click on the WiFi icon in the Menu Bar.